# What is the order and meaning of WindowManager.LayoutParams constructor parameters?

Tags: android, parameters, constructor, layoutparams, window-managers

I cannot find a description of the order and meaning of LayoutParams' 
constructor parameters.  This is all I can find on developer.android.com:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams() 
WindowManager.LayoutParams(int _type) 
WindowManager.LayoutParams(int _type, int _flags) 
WindowManager.LayoutParams(int _type, int _flags, int _format) 
WindowManager.LayoutParams(int w, int h, int _type, int _flags, int _format) 
WindowManager.LayoutParams(int w, int h, int xpos, int ypos, int _type, int _flags, int _format) 
WindowManager.LayoutParams(Parcel in)
```

..........with no further description.  I assume, for example, "int w" is 
setting the width parameter.

Does anyone know where there is a good description of this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!

And I finally solved it by setting "type" of LayoutParams as "TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT", which is always on top of application windows:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT